# Is Parse in JavaScript possible?

Tags: javascript, robotics

I have tried searching and haven't been able to see anything that can parse in JavaScript.

It would only have to parse a .txt (tab delimited) file with the following:

L123____Donald____Duck____247.09

S234____Mickey____Mouse___356.09

F456____Daffy_____Duck____1650.36

N876____Minnie____Mouse___60.45

It would have to pull out the number, first initial of first name, first initial of second name and then the number at the end (concentration). The first 3 L123, D and D could all be given a var, but the concentration number would have to get a separate one as I have to do some funky calculations and the assign it function in a liquid handling robot.

Any help on this gratefully received, even if it's only partial as I like to try and work things out ( sometimes ;-) )

I use this to test things at the moment because I don't know what else to use: https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Thank you

Comment: Check regular expresions https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: Yep, parsing usually involves regular expressions

Comment: @GramThanos—there is no need for a regular expression in this case. Parsing doesn't always use regular expressions because often there is a need to avoid patterns that appear in the data rather than represent tokens. Also, the data being parsed may not be sufficiently regular (e.g. HTML). So often parsers go character by character looking for tokens and data rather than using regular expressions.

Comment: @RobG , I don't suggest advance codes to amature users. Parsing using tokens with the help of states can became complex. I think that regular expression is a simple way of parsing strings in genera. So, since the OP said that he could not find parsers in javascript, I suggested Regular Expressions for him to read. Many languages support them, so it may help him with parsing in general, on any language.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = /* your data */;
var table = input.split("\n").map(line => line.split("\t")); // here's your table
```